# How damaging is to ride without a lambda sensor?

Tags: motorcycle, o2-sensor, yamaha

I am considering buying a motorcycle, a 2015 Yamaha MT 07. One possible problem with this bike: its lambda sensor was cut at some point in the past. I would have to replace it (which I am fine with - does not seem like a very expensive item), but what worries me is that the bike has been without this sensor for some time now. Isn't it likely that this has affected other components?

Basically my question is:
**Is it likely that some time (I don't know exactly how much) running without a lambda sensor has damaged my bike?**

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is yes. But that would most likely be limited to the catalytic converter. Most fuel injected vehicles run rich when they have a lack of information which the O2 (lambda) sensor would normally provide. The system runs it rich so as to protect internal components from detonation and other detrimental effects which happen due to a lean condition. The rich condition could cause damage to the catalytic converter.

Overall, it shouldn't create an issue for most any other part of the engine, but you may need to get a new catalytic converter. The current one could have either burnt itself out or become plugged overtime. Either way, you'd need to have it checked to see how it's operating.

Comment: Examine or ask the owner if the catalytic converter was removed to allow freer exhaust flow with a slight improvement in power.  Does your state require motorcycle emissions inspection or not?

Comment: @FDryer I don't think it was, but I will double checks. (The lambda sensor was apparently vandalized, the owner did not remove it on purpose). My country does not require this now but will likely require it at some point in the nearby future.

Comment: @paulster2 Thank you for your answer. I will have the catalytic converter checked.